# Activity shared element with drawn Rect

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am looking for a way to share a Rect between two activities. I would like to make it look like the Google Agenda app and animate the rectangle to the Toolbar of the next Activity. I could not find a way in the documentation. Is it possible?

[image: First activity]

[image: Second activity]

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is to make my Calendar view extend Viewgroup and create a View for events. Then the viewgroup will layout each view to the right position and making view transitions becomes possible.